# Selenium4 not working options.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False) for Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Selenium4 not working options.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False) for Firefox

i am using Selenium 4.0.0 + Firefox 93 +Python3.10
I am accessing website using a selenium Firefox web driver, but whenever I submit the form it asks for me to verify that am not a bot. What need to do for fix it

```
driver_path = "C:\\firefoxdriver\\geckodriver.exe"
binary_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"

service = Service(driver_path)

ops = options()
ops.binary_location = binary_path
# user-agent
ops.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0")
# disable webdriver mode
ops.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
ops.set_preference('dom.webnotifications.enabled', False)
ops.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)


browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=ops)
browser.get("https://bot.sannysoft.com/")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, так как на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском